# Reference request: Quasiconvex function

Tags: reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I read from Wiki page that the following definition [Quasiconvex function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiconvex_function) is proposed.

However, the reference in that page does not really lead to the book/papers which has the original definition of quasiconvex. I am wondering is there anybody know which book could be a good reference?

Thank you!

Comment: [Boyd and Vandenberghe's Convex Optimization](http://stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) is a good reference. Section 3.4 deals with quasiconvex functions and offers a variety of examples. It's not the original definition, but this book is considered the bible of convex optimization.